# converting string date time with microseconds to date object

Tags: python-3.x

I have a `datetime` coming from json data as `2017-03-28T00:00:00.000Z`

I have tried this

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(record_date, "%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S%f")
```

but this gives error:

*** ValueError: time data '2017-03-28T00:00:00.000Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S%f'

I have to compare the read date with user input date as `2017-03-28` format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your time is in isoformat, you need to use datetime's fromisoformat to convert it into a datetime object.

The [:-1] is to exclude the Z because datetime does not understand what that is. (2017-03-28T00:00:00.000Z is actually RFC 3339)

Z basically means UTC timezone (+00:00 GMT)

```py
from datetime import datetime
foo = "2017-03-28T00:00:00.000Z"
bar = datetime.fromisoformat(foo[:-1]) 
print(bar)
print(type(bar))
```

Gives you the result of, but this is now naive (unaware  of timezone)

```
2017-03-28 00:00:00
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

A quick workaround to make it timezone aware is

```
bar = datetime.fromisoformat(foo.replace('Z', '+00:00'))
print(bar)
2017-03-28 00:00:00+00:00

#If milliseconds are of concern then just strftime

bar = datetime.fromisoformat(foo.replace('Z', '+00:00')).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f %Z") 

# the Z displays UTC or equivalent time zone
2017-03-28 00:00:00:000000 UTC
```

The dateutil module is even better at handling this as it has native support for RFC 3339.

```py
import dateutil.parser

foo = "2017-03-28T00:00:00.000Z"
bar = dateutil.parser.isoparse(foo)

print(bar)
print(type(bar))

2017-03-28 00:00:00+00:00
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Comment: what is Z by the way ?

Comment: @ChangZhao I updated my answer to explain what it is, but it's the UTC timezone symbol for RFC 3339 isoformat